Jetpack Compose: What's the best practice for collecting StateFlow - in parent or child composable?
I have a Compose screen structure where ComposableA contains ComposableB and ComposableC. ComposableC needs data from a StateFlow in the ViewModel. I'm trying to determine the best approach for collecting this StateFlow.
Here are the two approaches I'm considering:
Approach 1: Collecting in Parent (ComposableA) and passing state down
kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _userState = MutableStateFlow<String>("")
    val userState = _userState.asStateFlow()
}

@Composable
fun ComposableA(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    val userState by viewModel.userState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    
    Column {
        ComposableB()
        ComposableC(userData = userState)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposableC(userData: String) {
    Text(text = userData)

Approach 2: Passing ViewModel to child and collecting there
kotlin
@Composable
fun ComposableA(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    Column {
        ComposableB()
        ComposableC(viewModel = viewModel)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposableC(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    val userState by viewModel.userState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    Text(text = userState)
}

Which approach is considered better practice ?

This question is similar to Jetpack Compose: Should I pass ViewModel down the component tree or use callbacks?. For the same reasons that view models shouldn't be passed down, unstable flow objects also shouldn't be passed around. Collect them at the location where you retrieve the view model (usually the top most composable the view model is used for) and only pass the collected value (not the state, the unwrapped value) down.

If the other question doesn't sufficiently answer this question as well then please [edit] this question and explain what is still unclear.
